# Save data finally after all action completed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, public, actionresult

hi please help me I have 5 model and I want to save all model at once so please help me

my models are

```
public partial class EmployeeMainTable
    {
        public EmployeeMainTable()
        {
            this.employee_DepartmentTable = new List<EmployeeDepartmentTable>();
        }



        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the Name")]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter date of joining")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

        public System.DateTime EmployeeDateOfJoining { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Required")]
        public int EmployeeDepartmentId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Designation Required")]
        public int EmployeeDesignationId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location Required")]
        public int EmployeeLocationId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee status Required")]
        public int EmployeeStatusId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Type Required")]
        public int EmployeeTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool EmployeeIsActive { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirmed Date Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime EmployeeConfirmDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Email required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = " Must be a valid e-mail address ")]
        public string EmployeeEmailId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Number Required")]
        public string EmployeeContactNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime EmployeeDateOfBirth { get; set; }


        public ICollection<EmployeeAssetsTable> employee_AssetsTable { get; set; }
        public  List<EmployeeDepartmentTable> employee_DepartmentTable { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeDesignationTable> employee_DesignationTable { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeEducationDetailTable> employee_EducationTable { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeFamilyTable> employee_FamilyTable { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeLocationTable> employee_LocationTable { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeStatusTable> employee_StatusTable { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeTypeTable> employee_TypeTable { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EmployeePreviousCompanyDetailTable> employee_PreviousCompanyDetailTable { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDocumentsTable> employee_DocumentTable { get; set; }
```

likewise I have 5 models

what I need I need to pas model from action to action and if I click submit button in last section data get saved from all model at once

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, can't you just have a property in model #2 for model#1, a property for model #2 and #1 in model #3, and so forth..

Or use custom ViewModels that's served to fit your purpose.

I just started with MVC so this is my novice advice, don't take it for granted.